Can I use "present perfect" here instead of "past simple"?
Below is the grammar question in my book:

Haida people _______ to represent their culture to the outside world even at a time when they ______ from devastating population loss due to introduced diseases.

Correct answer: managed / were suffering
The wrong one: have managed / suffered
Question: Is the wrong option is wrong because of the second part, which is in past simple instead of past simple continuous? If there were an option like (have managed / were suffering), would it be correct?

Neither option looks incorrect to me. It depends on whether the Haida people continue to "represent their culture" at the time of the statement. I, and doubtless many other native speakers, do not know about the Haida people so it would be impossible to detect any flaw here. It's purely factual. If they no longer exist, it's the former sentence. If they're still going, then it's the latter.

This is actually quite a difficult question and for a detailed discussion of it EL & U would be a better site. At ELL level I would simply say that either of the two options quoted would work but have slightly different meanings. But if you go for have managed in the first position, the second needs either to be "suffered" or "have suffered". "were suffered" does not work in that instance.

Thank you for replies. There is a tendency in English language education in Turkey that there musn't be any tense inconsistency in the same sentence. Like we cannnot use past tense and present tense in the same sentence at all. Maybe that's why I get confused all the time. For example, please look at the this sentence: "After returning home from holiday, I realized how much time I have wasted just sitting on the beach."  Is there a grammatical error here in this sentence? My teacher said I cannot use present perfect (have wasted) because of the past simple in the main clause (realized).

Your teacher is wrong. Wasted and have wasted are both valid, but they will mean different things. I've commented on the issue of matching tenses in my answer.

Your teacher is correct. After returning home means you are no longer on a beach therefore Present Perfect is not the best solution: "After returning home from holiday, I realized how much time I wasted just sitting on the beach.” The PP could be used if you didn't mention when you were on holiday , "Only now do I realize how much time I have wasted sitting on beaches.“

I disagree. Even if there is only one past event of sitting on a beach wasting time, I have wasted is still a valid choice. I may no longer be on the beach, but the time is still wasted time as I write. It's time I will never get back, no matter how long ago the holiday may have been. So although the PP is not required, it's certainly a valid literary choice. It all depends on the meaning I want to communicate.

what if I edit the question as: "After returning home from holiday, I realized how much time I ---- just sitting on the beach and thought I ---- more time exploring the area."  The answer is: had wasted / would rather have spent. A wrong answer is: have wasted / might have spent.  Now my question is: Is the wrong answer according to the answer key really wrong? There is no context because this is a multiple choice question in a grammar book. Can one still use present perfect in the first blank space?

@ern1z you need to post your question separately. The comment section is not really the ideal venue.

okay, I will post it as a seperate question later. Thank you for the warning.

When choosing tenses, don't just ask, Which tense is right? Learn to ask, Which tense says what I need to say?
Consider these simple examples:

I bought a new football.
I am buying a new football.
I will buy a new football.

It would be silly to ask, Which tense is right? They all are! But if we add a context...

I bought a new football yesterday.
I am buying a new football yesterday.
I will buy a new football yesterday.

...only the first sentence is correct, because the event is now set in the past. Change yesterday to today or tomorrow, and am buying/will buy is now right because we are talking about a present or future event.
This may seem obvious with such simple examples, but the same principle applies to the more complex sentence in the OP. Most tense choices will be correct, but depending on context they will mean different things:

Haida people managed to represent their culture to the outside world even at a time when they suffered from devastating population loss due to introduced diseases. (The simple past tenses imply that we are talking about one fixed period in the past.)


Haida people have managed to represent their culture to the outside world even at a time when they have suffered from devastating population loss due to introduced diseases. (Still referring to the past, but now pointing to the broad sweep of past time through to the present.)


Haida people are managing to represent their culture to the outside world even at a time when they are suffering from devastating population loss due to introduced diseases. (This sentence is talking about the situation now.)


Haida people are managing to represent their culture to the outside world even at a time when they have suffered from devastating population loss due to introduced diseases. (Here the tenses are different, but the sentence still has a valid meaning. It is describing the response of the Haida people now to the suffering they have experienced in the past.)

(I added the last example because of a comment from the OP that their teacher is insisting on matching tenses throughout a sentence. Sometimes that is helpful advice, but often it is simply wrong. There are many cases where tenses can vary at different points in a sentence.)

None of the examples you cite include the OP's multiple choice answers. Why?

In the quiz, the OP is given pairs of verb phrases that have to be substituted together. The whole point of the exercise is to select the matching pairs.

@Mari-LouA I guess a judgment call. I chose to contribute an answer based on general principles, rather than the specifics of the OP grammar question. I actually think a case could be made that the "wrong answer" from that example is also valid. That for me is the whole problem with these kinds of questions.
